# WinError 10022 error even after socket binding

Tags: python, sockets

I've been trying to build a basis for some simple networking, and I keep running into an issue of WinError 10022. Here's my class:

```
class SocketFactory:

    def __init__(self, secret):
        self.secret = secret

    def send(self, port, e_type, h_type, msg, ip="127.0.0.1"):

        s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
        print("Socket object successfully created.\n")

        s.bind((ip, port))
        print("Socket bound to port \n")

        while True:
            c, addr = s.accept()
            print('Connection established with ', addr)

            if h_type == 1:
                header = self.secret
                c.send(header, "utf-8")

            else:
                print("Incorrect header type. Exiting...\n")
                exit()

            if e_type == 1:
                c.send(bytes(msg, "utf-8"))

            else:
                print("Incorrect encoder type. Exiting...\n")
                exit()
        c.close()
```

The preliminary driver code is this:

```
from sockfactory import SocketFactory

print("Initializing masterserver setup...\n")

port = int(input("Enter port number: \n"))
#ip = str(input("Enter IPv4 address: \n"))
e_type = int(input("The encoding table for outbound bytes will be: \n" "1 = UTF-8 \n"))
h_type = int(input("The immutable header packet type will be: \n" "1 = Simple \n"))
msg = str(input("Enter packet payload: \n"))
secret = b'10000000011000101011110'

SocketFactory.send(port, e_type, h_type, msg, "127.0.0.1")
```

And the error message:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/EvESpirit/PycharmProjects/aaa/main", line 13, in <module>
    SocketFactory.send(port, e_type, h_type, msg, "127.0.0.1")
  File "C:\Users\EvESpirit\PycharmProjects\aaa\sockfactory.py", line 19, in send
    self.c, self.addr = s.accept()
  File "C:\Users\EvESpirit\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\socket.py", line 292, in accept
    fd, addr = self._accept()
OSError: [WinError 10022] An invalid argument was supplied
```

Can anyone help me here? What am I doing wrong and how can I do it better? Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You're missing `s.listen()` between `s.bind()` and `s.accept()`:

```
>>> from socket import *
>>> s=socket()
>>> s.bind(('',5000))
>>> s.accept()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python36\lib\socket.py", line 205, in accept
    fd, addr = self._accept()
OSError: [WinError 10022] An invalid argument was supplied
>>> s.listen()
>>> s.accept()  # waits here for a connection
```

Comment: do I need to s.listen() if all I'll use the bound socket for is sending two packets? My previously functional client code now throws WinError 10061.
I should clarify all the client does is connect to localhost on specified port and recv header and payload packets.

Comment: @EvE It's not a server socket, and can't call accept, without a listen.

Comment: It's supposed to be a server socket. When I now try to connect to the bound ip and port, it actively refuses the connection, and the server script seemingly does nothing after s.listen() which i've put after s.bind and before s.accept.

Comment: @EvE The server will wait on the `accept` for a connection.  If the client is not connecting correctly then it will keep waiting.  Are the client and server on the same machine?  You bound the server to `127.0.0.1` which is `localhost`.

Comment: @MarkTolonen Error 10061 (`WSAECONNREFUSED`) on the client side means either 1) the client is connecting to an IP that exists but the port is not bound and listening on that IP, 2) the listening socket's backlog of pending connections (established with `listen()`) is full, or 3) a firewall/antivirus/antimalware is blocking the connection from reaching the server. There is no way to know from the client side which is the actual reason.

Comment: @Remy Of course, or 4) the OP bound the server socket to localhost, but the client isn't on localhost, hence the clarifying question.  `s.bind(('',port))` would solve that issue.

Comment: @MarkTolonen If the client were connecting to the wrong IP altogether, a different error code than 10061 would usually be reported. Error 10061 would only happen in your scenario if the client were trying to connect to its own locahost which doesn't have such a port open.

Comment: I thought s.bind(('', port)) is functionally the same for testing purposes as 127.0.0.1 or socket.gethostname(). I'll try a round of fixes, probably move the definition for send into the main script instead of having issues with separate files - cause it worked before I started fragmenting it.

Comment: @EvE bind(('',port)) allows client connections from any interface not just localhost, but I missed your first comment that you were on localhost so in this case doesn’t matter.